# Как спарсить страницу с blazor-сайта?

Tags: c#, http, get, blazor

Есть страница с расписанием https://education.khai.edu/union/schedule/. Сайт сделан на `blazor`.

Когда я просто делаю запрос по ссылке то получаю просто `html` с скриптами для запуска работы `blazor`-а:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-UA">
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="НАУ «ХАІ»">
    <meta property="og:title" content="НАУ «ХАІ»">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content=https://education.khai.edu>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://education.khai.edu/img/main/logo_og.png">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
    <meta property="og:description" content="НАУ «ХАІ»">
    <title>НАУ «ХАІ»</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href=/img/main/khai_blue.svg?v=HwSFWwA-DOobBrzzaKEH3cOSJBvvvZHLfu-7tu8sNto>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href=/img/main/logo-apple-180.png?v=qU0dV6n08X1t3rB1aFavu34i6jOxUfwtLoJnEZRUrJg>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=/ui/app.css?v=BwP8DYoEIEE1S3C-kPYEod1-xpFKY0OI6NvBUxwLxS4 media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
    <link rel="preload" href="/ui/fa-brands-400.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preload" href="/ui/fa-light-300.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Blazor:{"sequence":1,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8MBhIHG65FtKlX56pWtbUtQZ6T285HAgOYeCRtbbe9JO4U4cZsYQJ9xvkrUrO01rnP\u002BgDnPMCl0MnI0E/fW58mYoqDZ3J1ztRz/DKm9\u002BABDrmL5ArBFfTFdeO82HHavNnd1E10j7gHBU9uqKmOW2otP1y5s/a\u002BnMT/P2jvdetcCcDQvdfLnX2/w747D4dYNA1MuoeBRlst63xJlks\u002BYeAfhhNMi1s961JEi777JANAEi\u002B9g\u002BNf7aS9sLn\u002BbJZ4m0IBrUnCcHbu3idntWrD/GDpgDVCwhrIhUIPhs8ITgqZHJdQprUnffKWflcMbJ6YyyWBBABTi2eOX/VMHvtFWxT8ABDgmXbyqC3vTfRe6VlwN5ibDYH/UKDkULoJuX\u002Bw\u002BQB2e3sSP1OddN/ud8pWe5\u002BuCo3\u002BkQ9OG6x2GLMXJHWgah"}-->
</head>
<body class="x-background">

<!--Blazor:{"sequence":0,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8MBhIHG65FtKlX56pWtbUtTdcyRUeUr\u002BhT344Mo3B4Gc0Gg3YwX1FY0c9owxv7oR1MDnLFR1BTJFjhuwYAjnROc3JT8UhSCkRbOdLVMuG0iwpNvwHNc47\u002BrguaHCTkDZKvZ9GKc0Jp\u002BCX0hcssqhCnp6eka\u002BG9Q7XF2B4ARhWnuJDKvUT\u002BbuWra063kFqG0Ixs4eWc4KrPRNS1KnTVu3QZrmx8r9dx6iyQXHjN/YgTqJhcv9LoQqWTfncbhBLwGm9l0BCTBLn3fGdJsOB6ES0lRwvVygmY7DA/2OGzhY7jGppr6UNaUXhdgo4xZDi3FkZgY3OL5xGS1p0bkc14UU9TM="}-->
    <script async src="/ui/app.js?v=3hNtGnhO8Vl6rh70OirKX4BnS6mxiiS5k9p3XAvofZA"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script src="_content/Blazor-Analytics/blazor-analytics.js"></script>
<script>
    async function connectionDown() {
        console.log("Blazor disconnected");
        location.reload();
    }

    function connectionUp() {
        console.log("Blazor connected");
    }

    window.Blazor.start({
        reconnectionOptions: {
            maxRetries: 10,
            retryIntervalMilliseconds: 500,
        },
        reconnectionHandler: {
            onConnectionDown: e => connectionDown(e),
            onConnectionUp: e => connectionUp(e)
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда я открываю страницу через браузер, то через поток `blazor`-а подгружаются нужные данные (тобиж `html` с расписанием). Как я могу спарсить их? Есть ли какой-то готвый `NuGet`-пакет или `.NET`-библиотека на `github`, которые являются обёрткой для взаимодействия с потоком `blazor`?

Comment: Смотрите сетевой лог браузера,оттуда и узнаете запрос, в ответ на который приходят данные.

Comment: я в него смотрел, но там же есть какой-то протокол специальный, если бы была хотя бы по нему документация где-нибудь, тогда было бы проще

Comment: Есть, зовется SignalR.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо!

Comment: Да, вы можете воспользоваться пакетом https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp, который поможет собрать информацию с помощью безголового браузера.

Comment: @АлексейЯкубин это библиотека - что-то по-типу маленького Selenium-а я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @iKuzmichov Верно, раз вы видите готовый к парсингу результат открывая браузер, значит это можно собрать с помощью этой библиотеки.